# How do I determine which index to change to remove a key lookup?

Tags: sql, indexing, key, lookup

Let's say you have a query that INNER JOINS the same table twice, using different fields, so different indexes are used. When you look at the execution plan, there is a troublesome Key Lookup. How do I know which index I should modify to get rid of the Key Lookup?

Comment: Can you add a graphic example?

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) You seem to be sure indexes are used for lookups; is this correct? 2) What do you mean by "troublesome key lookup"? Is it slow, inefficient, not working, etc. Please add the execution plan, and why you consider this troublesome.

Comment: Looking at the execution plan, I see two index seeks on the table that is connected twice, both are showing different indexes being used.  There is also a key lookup that is on this same table.  The key lookup is having to run millions of times, so changing one of the index to have an INCLUDE for the column that is being looked up will definitely help, but which index?  I don't want to add to both.

Comment: @ScottEvans I'll be glad to help, but the question is too abstract. Please add the query to be optimized and the current execution plan. My guess is that you are on the right track, essentially changing the indexes to become "covering indexes". If performance is critical I would convert both indexes. Then I could try reverting one of them at a time.

Comment: And... If you need to imporove an index I would try to move the filtering as early as possible to reduce lookups to a minimu. What database are you using? Heap- or index- based?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.